# TestExecutionListener is not listening at all

Tags: spring, spring-test, applicationcontext, spring-bean, spring-config

I have custom TestExecutionListener:

```
public class CustomExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {
    @Override
    public void beforeTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception { 
        // some code ...
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        // some code ...
    }
}
```

In my test class I configure it as follows:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    CustomExecutionListener.class
})
class MyTestClass {

    private static ApplicationContext appContext;

    @BeforeAll
    static void init() {
        appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        // register some configs for context here
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
    }
}
```

And `CustomExecutionListener` doesn't work - in debugger I even don't go there. I suppose that may be problem in the way I create `ApplicationContext`: may be `TestContext` encapsulates not my `appContext`? (I don't properly understand how `TestContext` is creating. May be someone could explain?) But even then it should at least go to the `beforeTestMethod` in lestener? Or not?

And second question: if it really encapsulates not my `appContext` how I can fix that? I. e. set my `appContext` to `testContext.getApplicationContext()`? I need to be able to extract beans from my `appContext` like `testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, the `TestExecutionListener` is only supported if you are using the *Spring TestContext Framework* (TCF).

Since you are using JUnit Jupiter (a.k.a., JUnit 5), you need to annotate your test class with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` or alternatively with `@SpringJUnitConfig` or `@SpringJUnitWebConfig`.

Also, you should not create your `ApplicationContext` programmatically. Rather, you let the TCF do that for you -- for example, by specifying declaratively which configuration classes to use via `@ContextConfiguration`, `@SpringJUnitConfig`, or `@SpringJUnitWebConfig`.

In general, I recommend you read the [Testing chapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing) of the Spring Reference Manual, and if that doesn't help enough you can certainly find tutorials for "integration testing with Spring" online.

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `@Before` which is not required static methods??

```
private static ApplicationContext appContext;

@Before
public void init() {
    if(appContext == null) {
        appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        // register some configs for context here
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it didn't help